# Is there a way to only load a Twig extends conditionally?

Tags: twig

I want to do what this code block implies:

```
{% if load_base %}
  {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

So if load_base isn't true, I don't want any extends at all.  This template only has one block of content in it and I want that content printed just as if the {% extends %} line was never included.

I did see about [conditional inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#conditional-inheritance) in the docs, but that still requires me to make a empty template file which seems like a hack.  Is there any better way of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Creating empty template will not work either. Extending template does only modify blocks with identical names.

There is example:
http://twigfiddle.com/hx5a0e

```
{# main.twig #}
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block a %}a{% endblock %}
{% block b %}b{% endblock %}
```

,

```
{# base.twig #}
{% block a %}{% endblock %}
```

Output of `main.twig` will be always `a`. Content of block `b` is just ignored, because it's not in base template. So "extending nothing" doesn't make sense, because there will be no output at all.

You must write simple template with nothing but block definitions in proper order.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... that's what I meant by "empty template"... is nothing but the empty blocks.  It just sucks that the template I'm working with outputs the exact code I want if I take out the extends tag.  But then sometimes I want the code as outputted with the extends tag.  And there's no way to make a conditional do that.